# Create a pydantic.BaseModel definition with external class or dictionary

Tags: python, class, inheritance, metaclass, pydantic

I have a (dynamic) definition of a simple class, like so:

```py
class Simple:
    val: int = 1
```

I intend to use this definition to build a `pydantic.BaseModel`, so it can be defined from the `Simple` class; basically doing this, but via `type`, under a metaclass structure where the `Simple` class is retrieved from.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SimpleModel(Simple, BaseModel):
    pass

# Actual ways tried:
SimpleModel = type('SimpleModel', (Simple, BaseModel), {})
# or
SimpleModel = type('SimpleModel', (BaseModel, ), Simple.__annotations__)
```

However, this approach was not returning a model class with the parameters from the `Simple` class.

I understand that the `BaseModel` already uses a rather complex metaclass under the hood, however, my intended implementation is also under a metaclass, where I intend to *dynamically* transfer the `Simple` class into a `BaseModel` from pydantic.

Your suggestions will be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working by first, casting my `Simple` class to be a dataclass from pydantic, then getting a pydantic model from it.

I am not an expert in pydantic, so would not mind your views on the approach.

```py
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

SimpleModel = dataclass(Simple).__pydantic_model__
```

The trouble I did however find (same with an answer provided by @jsbueno), that when declaring annotation for data type for `pathlib.Path` (as an example) with `BaseModel` directly, the string value provided gets coerced to the annotation data type. But with my or @jsbueno approaches, the data type remains original (no coercion).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `type` passing a dictionary made of `SimpleModel`'s `__dict__` attribute - that will contain your fileds default values and the `__annotations__` attribute, which are enough information for Pydantic to do its thing.

I just would just take the extra step of deleting the `__weakref__` attribute that is created by default in the plain "SimpleModel" before doing that - to avoid it pointing to the wrong class.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Simple:
    val: int = 1

new_namespace = dict(Simple.__dict__)  # copies the class dictproxy into a plain dictionary
del new_namespace["__weakref__"]
SimpleModel = type("SimpleModel", (BaseModel,), new_namespace)
```

and we have

```py
In [58]: SimpleModel.schema()                                                                                                                                               
Out[58]: 
{'title': 'Simple',
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {'one_val': {'title': 'One Val',
   'default': 1,
   'type': 'integer'}}}
```

That works - but since Pydantic is complex, to make it more futureproof, it might be better to use the Pydantic's metaclass supplied namespace object instead of a plain dictionary - the formal way to do that is by using
the helper functions in the `types` model:

```
import types

from pydantic import BaseModel

class Simple:
    val: int = 1
SimpleModel = types.new_class(
    "SimpleModel",
     (BaseModel,),
     exec_body=lambda ns:ns.update(
         {key: val for key, val in Simple.__dict__.items()
             if not key.startswith("_")}
     )
)
```

The `new_type` call computes the appropriate metaclass, and pass the correct namespace object to the callback in the `exec_body` argument. There, we just fill it with the contents of the dict on your dynamic class.

Here, I opted to update the namespace and filter all "_" values in a single line, but you can define the function  passes to "exec_body" as a full multiline function and filter the contents you want out more carefully.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It's rather a lengthy way of getting there, but it certainly worked. I don't mind this being long or messy, as it's performed in a metaclass. I did however, come up with another way to achieve this. I will add my own answer here, and would like you opinion on it?

Comment: There is hardly anything "messy" on the code above - I even stated a short version, that just need an intermediate variable and an extra line to remove the `__weakref__` member, which could cause strange and undebuggable side effects. The long answer is a plain function call instead of calling `type`, with similar code to avoid unwanted elements to be copied over. But yes, since there is a dataclass decorator that is shipped with Pydantic, that should be used - your answer is even more "future proof".

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I will be extensively covering my implementation in unit tests soon, so I will keep your implementation as an option in case something decides to stop working.